# Why Capypara + Rspect tests still pass even though I delete application.js file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit

I have rails app and have some ajax call in application.js file. O have rspec, capybara, webkit, factorygirl and databasecleaner for testing. I wrote feature tests which all pass. Then accidentally delete application.js file and run the tests, they still pass. Please help me to find out why. Thanks so much.

PS: if you downvote my question, please at least tell me why. I have been searching for answers but couldn't find one.

Comment: have you tried with `rake assets:clean` , `rake assets:clobber` and `rake assets:precompile` ?

Comment: @fabersky `rake assets:clobber` worked, those cached file in public folder was the reason. Thanks so much man!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with

```
rake assets:clobber
```

This will remove compiled assets and clean them.

Comment: thanks! in my case was driving nuts because my feature tests were calling to a deleted method