# Rails 5 Capybara Test Routing Error public/assets

Tags: routes, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

My problem is that I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.zedroot.org/cucumber-capybara-show-me-the-page-with-the-css-stylesheets/) to try to load the assets in test environment when debugging with Capybara method `save_and_open_page`, but I get the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/public/assets/application-22cc3ed14274a8cdae6670ce999946a627b5fd03c71819fbe4453118dca5ff40.css">
```

I added the following parameters in `environments/test.rb` to try to make them work but I still getting this error.

```
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.prefix = '../public/assets/'
config.assets.quiet = true
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40441986/1033737

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work. I also tried to install yarn but doesn't help too.

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: I'm using `:selenium_chrome`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this confid in `test.rb` and worked:

```
config.assets.prefix = '../public/assets/'
```

to

```
config.assets.prefix = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've precompiled your assets in the test environment, then rather than following that article (which is 3 years old and out of date), you should be able to set `Capybara.asset_host` to whatever the address of your dev or test instance is - something like

```
Capybara.asset_host = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
```

This will add that into a base tag in the document when saving and opening the page.

Comment: I tried this and also didn't help. I tried this config with `config.assets.prefix = ""` but I tested commenting `Capybara.asset_host = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'` and the assets keep working. Do you know why?

Comment: Huh?  I don't understand you're question -- what do you mean the assets keep working? I thought the whole issue was they weren't working?  If you mean the assets in the normal test run keep working, that's because `Capybara.asset_host` only affects pages during saving -- Did it add a `base` tag to the document it saved and opened?  If so, did you have your dev instance running when the document was opened?  Had you precompiled your test assets?

Comment: I'm sorry by the confusing! I'll rephrase myself. I tried with the exact configs as the question and with `Capybara.asset_host = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'` and didn't work.

Comment: @RodrigoChaves But did it add the `base` tag to the document it saved and opened? You shouldn't need to make any of the changes from the tutorial, just set `asset_host`, precompile your assets for the test env before running your test, and leave your dev env running (if specifying port 3000 in asset_host, assuming your dev env is running on 3000)